# Он довольствуется человеческою природою(,) как она есть

Tags: пунктуация

> Он довольствуется человеческою природою, как она есть, ― это идеал
> грубый и поверхностный, и мы знаем, что попытки к его реализации
> только утверждают и умножают уже господствующие в мире зло и безумие.

В. С. Соловьев. Три речи в память Достоевского (1881-1883)

Зачем здесь запятая перед "как она есть"? Здесь же значение ― РЕАЛЬНО, ОБЪЕКТИВНО, БЕЗ ПРИКРАС?

Comment: Здесь падежи разные, а "так" не подходит. Наверно, надо: *какою она есть*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Он довОльствуется / человеческою прирОдою (в том виде),// **как она есть**, ― это идеал грубый и поверхностный...*

В этом предложении лучше поставить запятую, считая оборот **придаточным определительным предложением.** При данной структуре  его сложно прочитать в одну фразу, без четко обозначенной паузы.

Однако **при меньшей распространенности**  оборот может быть **необособленным обстоятельством**, например:

*Он видит человеческую природу **как она есть** (объективно, без прикрас).*

Comment: Всё так, чуть-чуть непонятна "меньшая распространенность":  количество слов такое же, только одно покороче. Или вы имеете в виду то, что убрали после тире?

Comment: Надо еще слоги посчитать ;)  В первом варианте приходится делать еще одну произносительную паузу.

Comment: Да-да, тоже хотел об этом сказать.

Comment: "В том виде" нельзя опускать, потому что там существительное ("вид"), нельзя сказать, что именно оно там подразумевается. В таких случаях подстановка неверна. Так что грамматику это не объясняет. В одном ответе Грамота говорит о стилистической проблеме, из-за того что падежи не совпадают.

Comment: Не нравится – ничего не подставляйте, ага? Коррелят (указательное слово) не является обязательным элементом для придаточных определительных предложений.

Comment: Не является, но какое-то местоимение (без существительного) должно подставляться. Впрочем, это 19 век, может, тогда это было нормой (была причина).